# Removing common factors when an expression is within absolute value bars

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

I'm working through a derivative problem involving inverse trig functions from a calculus course on Udemy. The part of this problem I'm having trouble with is the simplification step at the very end. A snippet of the work-through is pictured below:

[image]

How is the expression with the red border simplified to the expression with the green border? In my mind, taking the common factor of x out of the absolute value expression changes the value of the surrounding expression for values of x < 0, right? I'm probably missing something... My math skills are rusty...

[image]

EDIT: Here's the original problem:

[image: original problem]

Comment: You have a point. Maybe somewhere earlier it was assumed $x>0$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I was wondering about that, but I don't think it's assumed. I added an image of the original problem for more context. Perhaps I don't fully understand everything that's going on in the original problem and maybe something in there does imply that x > 0.

Comment: Assuming no typo or critically missing context, I agree with both you and @GerryMyerson.  That is, the issue simplifies to whether one can infer that $$\frac{x}{|x|} = 1,$$ and, as you have indicated, that inference is not generally valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression on the left (in red) is nonnegative. The expression on the right (in green) is negative for negative values of x. Also, the answer is only real if $|x| > 1$. So they are only equal if x is assumed positive.